# Error trying to convert objects in MapStruct

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mapstruct

I'm trying to convert a ClassDomain class into a ClassEntity but it's not working because it's returning the error below and I don't know how to solve it:

```
error: The return type List<DomainClass> is an abstract class or interface. Provide a non abstract / non interface result type or a factory method.
```

Class DataDomainClass:

```
public class DataDomainClass{
    private List<DomainClass> data;
    }
```

Class EntityClass:

```
public class EntityClass {

    private String codDist;

    private String numF;

    private String textJus;

    private Boolean valResol;
    }
```

Convert mapper:

```
DataDomainClass map(EntityClass entity);
```

The DomainClass class contains the same fields as the EntityClass class.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Then shouldn't the mapper's return type be `DomainClass`, and not `DataDomainClass`?

Comment: It could, but it can't because this return comes from a request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no clear out-of-box implementation. MapStruct does not support mapping from non-iterable to iterable. Workaround described in [mapstruct-examples](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct-examples/pull/33/files#diff-813ae9742ebf9ffa51488e83f7ded05b2ac2f38e7b74b807ab0a349a5228196b). This is more general solution for primitives.

For your case simplest solutions are:

**Solution 1: custom method for mapping entity to List**

```java
import org.mapstruct.Mapper;
import org.mapstruct.Mapping;
import org.mapstruct.factory.Mappers;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

@Mapper
public interface DomainMapper {
    DomainMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(DomainMapper.class);

    @Mapping(target = "data", source = "entity")
    DataDomainClass map(EntityClass entity);

    DomainClass toDomain(EntityClass entity);

    default List<DomainClass> toList(EntityClass entity) {
        return entity != null ? Collections.singletonList(toDomain(entity)) :
                                new ArrayList<>();
    }
}
```

Generated code:

```java
public class DomainMapperImpl implements DomainMapper {

    @Override
    public DataDomainClass map(EntityClass entity) {
        if ( entity == null ) {
            return null;
        }
        DataDomainClass dataDomainClass = new DataDomainClass();
        dataDomainClass.data = toList( entity );
        return dataDomainClass;
    }

    @Override
    public DomainClass toDomain(EntityClass entity) {
        if ( entity == null ) {
            return null;
        }
        DomainClass domainClass = new DomainClass();
        domainClass.codDist = entity.codDist;
        domainClass.numF = entity.numF;
        domainClass.textJus = entity.textJus;
        domainClass.valResol = entity.valResol;
        return domainClass;
    }
}
```

**Solution 2: [Expression](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#expressions)**

```java
import org.mapstruct.*;
import org.mapstruct.factory.Mappers;

import java.util.Collections;

@Mapper(imports = {Collections.class})
public interface DomainMapper {
    DomainMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(DomainMapper.class);

    @Mapping(target = "data", expression = "java(Collections.singletonList(toDomain(entity)))")
    DataDomainClass map(EntityClass entity);

    DomainClass toDomain(EntityClass entity);
}
```

Generated code:

```java
public class DomainMapperImpl implements DomainMapper {

    @Override
    public DataDomainClass map(EntityClass entity) {
        if ( entity == null ) {
            return null;
        }
        DataDomainClass dataDomainClass = new DataDomainClass();
        dataDomainClass.data = Collections.singletonList(toDomain(entity));
        return dataDomainClass;
    }

    @Override
    public DomainClass toDomain(EntityClass entity) {
        if ( entity == null ) {
            return null;
        }
        DomainClass domainClass = new DomainClass();
        domainClass.codDist = entity.codDist;
        domainClass.numF = entity.numF;
        domainClass.textJus = entity.textJus;
        domainClass.valResol = entity.valResol;
        return domainClass;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Iterable to non-iterable mapping also is not supported. Workaround for primitive types described at [iterable-to-non-iterable](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct-examples/tree/master/mapstruct-iterable-to-non-iterable/src/main/java/com/mycompany/mapper).

Example of reverse mapping for your case:

```java
@Mapper
public interface DomainMapper {
    DomainMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(DomainMapper.class);

    default EntityClass map(DataDomainClass dataDomainClass) {        
        return dataDomainClass != null && dataDomainClass.data != null && !dataDomainClass.data.isEmpty() ? toEntity(dataDomainClass.data.get(0)) : null;
    }

    EntityClass toEntity(DomainClass domainClass);
}
```

Comment: Nice! and what would the reverse conversion look like?
EntityClass map(List<DomainClass> domain);

Comment: I have added an example for reverse mapping to the answer

Comment: But this error message says different. I confirm your solution, which helped me too, but this message says totally different thing. Anyways thanks for your response!

Answer (score 1):

MapStruct can't map non-iterable type to iterable, especially mapping non-iterable to a nested collection.

Here's several solutions:

1. Change method signatures so input and output parameters will be the same type(iterable or non-iterable) and do the wrapping further in code. This is the most preferable solution
2. Also you can create default method in your interface to do the wrapping there:

   ```
   @Mapper
   public interface Entity2DomainMapper {

       DomainClass entity2Domain(EntityClass raw);

       default DataDomainClass from(EntityClass raw) {
           DomainClass nested = entity2Domain(raw);
           return DataDomainClass.of(List.of(nested));
       }
   }
   ```

   So instead of calling auto-generated method you'll call default method
3. Or if you wanna hide all the wrapping inside MapStruct mapper you can use `@AfterMapping`, but it still will require you to implement the wrapping by yourself

```
@Mapper
public abstract class Entity2DomainMapper2 {
    abstract DomainClass entity2Domain(EntityClass raw);

    abstract DataDomainClass entity2DataDomain(EntityClass raw);

    @AfterMapping
    protected void afterMapping(EntityClass raw, @MappingTarget DataDomainClass target) {
        if (target.getNested() == null) {
            target.setNested(new ArrayList<>());
        }
        DomainClass nested = entity2Domain(raw);
        target.getNested().add(nested);
    }
}
```

UPD: You can also use `extensions` as Eugene specified, but the cleanest approach will be to keep mapper as simple as possible(ideally there should be no non-autogenerated code at all) and handle populating `List<DomainClass>` somewhere else in code.